# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt5

I tried to install some disassembler using

```
$sudo cmake ../edb-debugger-master
```

but it's giving me an following error

```
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Checking for module 'libgvc>=2.38.0'
-- 
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:26 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg" with any
of the following names:
Qt5SvgConfig.cmake
qt5svg-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Svg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Svg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Svg"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
src/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kanna/Desktop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

If you take a look at this picture, you can see both Qt5 (dependency for this software) and `Qt5SvgConfig.cmake` are present.

[image]

Then why is it still giving me an error?

Comment: Try typing `find ~/Qt5.7.0 -name '*.cmake'` to locate all the Cmake find files.

Comment: I just did and output was 

https://www.itextpad.com/pBWJkHa4iG

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed this problem by doing two things. First install all  qt dev libraries just search in synaptic or try installing all of these.

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake qt5-default qtscript5-dev libssl-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libsdl2-dev libasound2 libxmu-dev libxi-dev freeglut3-dev libasound2-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libxrandr-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev
```

After that make sure to clone project this way. It also says that in README.
 `git clone --recursive https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger.git`

It worked after this.

Comment: I had the same problem when executing the cmake command from these instructions for building Marble: https://marble.kde.org/sources.php

Answer (score 23):

It has been solved on my side with:

```
sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev
```

Comment: And since if you're missing one, you're probably missing more... try `sudo apt install libqt5*-dev`

Comment: Thanks Byteboon! I had to make sure I remembered to put the command in quotes on my system as ZSH was looking for files with the names. `sudo apt install "libqt5*-dev"`

Answer (score 0):

Open `terminal` and set the environment variable `Qt5Svg_DIR` to dir containing those file.

`export Qt5Svg_DIR=~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Svg`

then run the cmake command in same terminal. Please check the path for environment variable once in above line.

Comment: @james-park Please upload the output.log in case this doesn't works.

Comment: export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Svg

Comment: I'm asking for `CMakeOutput.log` file .? Can you plz upload it

Comment: Since StackOverflow doesn't allow me to upload any file other than picture.

here is a link for output.log
https://www.itextpad.com/kanna 
Thanks for helping by the way

Comment: Yes I tried 
export Qt5Svg_DIR=~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Svg
but still giving me an same error